# Regex for indenting lines

Tags: html, regex, indentation

I'm trying to mass indent my code in the way I prefer it - that is, each line should be indented by groups of 4 spaces, depending on how 'deep' that line is in code (e.g. children elements should get 4 extra than their parent).

Currently everything has 1 space (a sample from my code):

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="loadfiles.js"></script>
 </head>
...
```

I'd like to have it get 4 spaces for the first level, 8 for the second etc. So basically multiply the amount with 4.

I tried this Regex replace command:

```
^ (.*)$      // search for
    $1       // replace with
```

But this only replaces the first space  of each line with 4 spaces. How can I also make it replace 2 spaces with 8 spaces etc.?

Thanks.

Comment: enable the `global` flag in your RegEx

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
^(\s+)  //search for
$1$1$1$1 //replace with
```

Answer (score 1):

I think Cybernate is right. Just thought I'd mention you could accomplish this without any code by using block edit (column edit) feature in your favorite text editor (such as Notepad++, Coda etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are on a system with perl, you could do this:

```
cat original.html | perl -lpe 's/^( +)/" "x(length($1) * 4)/e' > indented.html
```

That is, replace spaces in the beginning of a row by four times as many spaces.